# Tell MySQL how to physically store records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have studied to improve performances of a database they can be set 2 type of organization: primary organization and secondary organization.

The first sets how to physically save the file records, the seconds creates some indexes to improve the access to the records.
Now I know how to create some indexes in MySQL, I'm not talking about it, but I would like to know how to tell MySQL how physically store the records according to an attribute to create one of the following:

- file heap

- sorted file

- hash file
Is there a way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Forcing the engine type is not often required, so you'll have to specify more details.

Comment: I'm talking from a pratical point of view, records can be stored in heap files, sorted files or hash files. The point is how can I get this goal with mysql?

Comment: See my answer. I'm still not sure why you'd want to do this though - it's fairly unusual. This is why you're using a RDMS.

Comment: I do not want to do that, I only want to understand how I could do it, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL stores everything in *pages*, in groups of *extent* size. There is no configuration for this beyond page size.

See: [File Space Management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-space.html)

Only memory tables support an index type other than B-tree. Memory tables also support a hash index.

Note that hash indexes only support equal/not equal searches.

See: [Comparison of B-Tree and Hash Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basic table creation sytax. [Chapter 14 Storage Engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html)

Here are a couple of examples straight from the manual:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

or

```
 CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = HEAP;
```